# Is blond hair unclean?

Tags: leviticus

According to Leviticus 13:30 is blond hair unclean?

> If the priest looks at the plague and finds that it is deeper than the
>   rest of the skin, **and the hair in it is golden yellow and thin**, the priest
>   shall pronounce him unclean: it is a scab, a leprosy on the head or
>   beard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious that this is talking about disease, and not naturally blond hair.

Comment: So there's unclean and clean blonde hair? If yes, how can I distinguish clean (natural) blonde hair from unclean blonde hair?

Comment: @user47998 - Only _unclean_ blond hair is unclean, clean blond hair isn't.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has taken a Bible verse out of context and appears to be twisting the meaning of Scripture.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with discrimination, nor do I take things out of context.
This plague can also cover the whole body and be genetically inherited, but if it affected the whole body, one is clean.

Comment: Only to the extent to which it grows in or around plague-wounds, on an individual belonging to a nation whose hair is not otherwise known to be either particularly thin or light-colored.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer: no.** Some translations say that it is *white* not *yellow* but the basic meaning is the same, this verse is clearly a reference to harmful skin diseases typically translated leprosy but actually describing a broad category of skin diseases, and would never have been applied to persons simply born blonde, with albinism, or turning white with age. For example:

> The white spots, upon which so much diagnostic stress was laid, were
>   in all likelihood those of vitiligo, a disease quite common in
>   tropical countries, and characterized by bright white spots, the hairs
>   on which also become white[.](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/9774-leprosy)

Incidentally, if plucked out before examination, the hair does not make one unclean so even if it did refer to blonde people, as long as they plucked themselves bald, they would not be unclean.

Comment: The "some translations" are then wrong, because the Hebrew word tsahob (6669) literally means "yellow" and not "white".

Comment: Leviticus 13:30 uses the term for yellow-ish, but 13:3, 10, 20, 21 and 26 all us *laban* which literally means white. See: https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H3836&t=KJV

Comment: Right, but the color white refers to the color of the skin, the color yellow refers to the hair.
I didn't ask about the colour of the skin but about the colour of the hair.

Comment: Did you read the verses I cited? https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/lev/13/3/p0/t_conc_103003 read: "and when the hair is turned white". In addition, it is (1) a "change" in color (i.e. you are not a natural blonde) is (2) always in combination with and abnormal skin changes. If I had a patch of skin change color, and then the hair on that patch of skin also changed color, it does not make me blonde, but it does indicate that I might have a medical problem.

Comment: The passage you mentioned refers to another plague, the plague I mentioned is from verse 29-37 and in it the unclean color of the hair is called "yellow". You should note that in this chapter there is talk of various plagues. And of course a plague is a change of the body, but this change can even be inherited, so that the descendants may think it is natural.(2. Kings 5:27)

Comment: and to say it is only a combination is wrong, the plague can cover the whole body. (Levitikus 13:12-13)

Comment: @user47998 Leviticus 13:12-14 says if the plague covers their whole body, he's clean (unless there's an open sore).